# accessing embedded object with jquery not working in firefox 3.6

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, firefox3.6

this code in my plugin used to work just fine:

```
jQuery('#embedded_obj', context).get(0).getVersion();
```

and the html...

```
<object id="embedded_obj" type="application/x-versionchecker-1.0.0.1"></object>
```

Basically trying to get the properties from an embedded object. But it looks like get(0) is returning an html object instead of the actual embedded object.

For example, if I do:

```
var launcher = jQuery('#embedded_obj', context).get(0);

for(prop in launcher){
  alert(prop + ': ' + launcher[prop]);
}
```

... it alerts things like "getElementByNode," "scrollWidth," "clientLeft," "clientTop" etc.

Again this worked before Firefox 3.6. Has anyone else seen this or have any ideas/suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? Have you recently updated it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you sure it worked before? jQuery(..).get(..) always returns a DOM object (in this case the `<object>` element), so are you sure you didn't use a syntax like

```
var launcher = new VersionChecker(jQuery("#embedded_obj").get(0));
alert(launcher.getVersion());
```

So with a constructor that takes care of the link between the HTML DOM element and the actual embedded object?

If so, did you check it with a small `test.html` file or so and open this with the two browsers to verify the difference in behaviour?

Edit: nevermind, there is really something strange going on indeed with the object-tag after I googled about it and stumbled on http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-object-get-0-is-not-a-dom-element-in-ff-but-is-in-safari-is-this-a-bug

Comment: Hi, thanks for the idea - I did try with a test.html using document.getElementById(...) instead of jQuery, and still had an issue, so I'm pretty sure it's something with the custom plug-in that needs to change. (I guess FF changed something with the way plug-ins work in 3.6.) Anyway thanks!